# From #define to function

Tags: c++, c

I have this code inside a function but I am not able to understand what it does.

```
....
#define ascend(i) do {\
            int h = nodes[i].heavyindex;\
            int p = nodes[i].heavypos;\
            m##i = max(m##i + paths[h].ftree.sum(p), paths[h].stree.max_(0, p));\
            i = paths[h].parent;\
        } while (0)
    while (nodes[a].heavyindex != nodes[b].heavyindex) {
        if (nodes[a].heavyindex > nodes[b].heavyindex) {
            ascend(a);
        } else {
            ascend(b);
        }
    }
#undef ascend
...
```

The code of `#define`, I think, is:

```
#define ascend(i) do {\
            int h = nodes[i].heavyindex;\
            int p = nodes[i].heavypos;\
            m##i = max(m##i + paths[h].ftree.sum(p), paths[h].stree.max_(0, p));\
            i = paths[h].parent;\
        } while (0)
```

so the real code inside the function is only this:

```
while (nodes[a].heavyindex != nodes[b].heavyindex) {
        if (nodes[a].heavyindex > nodes[b].heavyindex) {
            ascend(a);
        } else {
            ascend(b);
        }
    }
```

1) It is right?
2) I want to move the code of the `#define` inside a function to better understand what it does, but how I translate the following line?

```
m##i = max(m##i + paths[h].ftree.sum(p), paths[h].stree.max_(0, p));\
```

Comment: `m##i` is using the token-pasting operator, it will become either `ma` or `mb`.  You'll need to pass the function a pointer (or in C++, a reference) to it, in order to read and write it from inside the function.

Comment: Most compilers can output the preprocessed source code. For Gcc, it's `gcc -E`.

Comment: What's the type of `ma` and `mb`?

Comment: Regardomg the `do{} while(0)` construct, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Comment: [zenith](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3425536/zenith) `ma` and `mb` are int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. As mentioned by [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) in the comments, `##` is the token-pasting operator. So with `#define f(i) m##i` defined, `f(a)` will expand to `ma`, `f(b)` will expand to `mb`, etc.

   Since that's only possible with the preprocessor, you have to think of something else to implement it as a function. Passing `ma` and `mb` by reference would be a good idea. It could look something like this:

   ```
   ascend(T& mi) {
       ...
       mi = max(mi + paths[h].ftree.sum(p), paths[h].stree.max_(0, p)); 
       ...
   }
   ```

   Where `T` is the type of `ma` and `mb`. If they're of different types, you need to make it a function template.

Comment: It's important to note that this is a C++ answer.  If OP is really looking for a C answer, this will need some (minor) semantic cleanup, and a function template is not possible.